# Salesforce1 New Event Publisher Action

Tags: apex, salesforce1-app, event, publisher-action

I have overridden Event new button in salesforce but when I am opening new event action from Salesforce1, its taking me to standard page. I have enabled page for mobile appication too. Please advice.

Comment: Some help on this will be appreciated.